# Unable to replace Unicode characters with sed or vim

Tags: vim, awk, unicode, sed, utf-8

I have a file with what I believe to be a unicode type and would like to remove them with sed or some other unix utility.  I have tried few options and for some reason unable to remove those characters.  Test cases shown with single line (head -n1)

Attempt 1:

```
> head -n1 file1.txt | hexdump -C  # Hexdump line 1
output:
00000000  47 72 6f 75 70 c2 a0 20  20 20 53 69 67 6e 61 6c  |Group..   Signal|
00000010  c2 a0 6e 61 6d 65 c2 a0  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |..name..        |
00000020  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |                |
00000030  55 6e 69 74 c2 a0 20 74  79 70 65 c2 a0 44 65 73  |Unit.. type..Des|
00000040  63 72 69 70 74 69 6f 6e  c2 a0 0d 0a              |cription....|
0000004c
```

Now replace "c2 a0" above

```
> head -n1 file1.txt | sed 's/\xc2\xa0//g' | hexdump -C
or
> head -n1 file1.txt | sed 's/\x{c2a0}//g  | hexdump -C 
00000000  47 72 6f 75 70 c2 a0 20  20 20 53 69 67 6e 61 6c  |Group..   Signal|
00000010  c2 a0 6e 61 6d 65 c2 a0  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |..name..        |
00000020  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |                |
00000030  55 6e 69 74 c2 a0 20 74  79 70 65 c2 a0 44 65 73  |Unit.. type..Des|
00000040  63 72 69 70 74 69 6f 6e  c2 a0 0d 0a              |cription....|
```

No replacements happend

Attempt 2: Using vim

```
vim file1.txt
:set nobomb
:set fileencoding=utf-8
:wq
```

Used sed again and no replacements happened.  How do I replace or remove those characters (hex "c2a0")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally ended up using Perl which successfully removed the unicode chars.

```
> perl -v
This is perl 5, version 18, subversion 2 (v5.18.2) built for darwin-thread-multi-2level

> perl -pi -e 's/\x{c2}\x{a0}//g' file1.txt
> head -n1 file1.txt | hexdump -C
00000000  47 72 6f 75 70 20 20 20  53 69 67 6e 61 6c 6e 61  |Group   Signalna|
00000010  6d 65 20 20 20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |me              |
00000020  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  20 20 55 6e 69 74 20 74  |          Unit t|
00000030  79 70 65 44 65 73 63 72  69 70 74 69 6f 6e 0d 0a  |ypeDescription..|
00000040
```